# how to create table in continued on next page

Tags: longtable, tabularx

I like to continued on next page also having 100 lines of data throwing error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}% new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% new
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{showframe}% only for show page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{l % table width is equal text height
                                  >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L% new column type
                                  >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                                  >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                                  >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                                  l}
    \toprule % added rules
\textbf{Author}  & \textbf{Mechanism} & \textbf{Features} & \textbf{Protocol}   & \textbf{Attacks} & \textbf{Limitations} \\
    \midrule
R. Molva et al., & Across domains     & Mutual \& one way authentication 
                                                           & Stateless Authentication 
                                                                                & Eavesdroppers    & GSM \\
    \addlinespace
Hung-Yu et al.,  & Subscriber identity& Mutual authentication Non repudiation 
                                                           & Public key         & Subscriber ID Compromised session key 
                                                                                                   & GSM \\
    \addlinespace
Muxiang Zhang    & Fresh key          & Mutual authentication \& eliminate synchronisation & AP-AKA symetric key & Redirection attack & 3GPP \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the tabular material will occupy at least two pages (and possibly more), you need an environment that can break across pages. Neither the `sidewaystable` nor the `tabularx` environments are suitable. Instead, I suggest you use a `longtable` environment (so that header and footer information is provided on each page) embedded in a `landscape` environment (provided by the `pdflscape` package. Depending on your page and text block parameters, you'll probably need to fiddle a bit with the column widths. The good news is that you'll only need to do this once.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, longtable, ragged2e, pdflscape}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{@{}l P{3cm} P{4cm} P{3cm} P{3cm} l @{}}
% header information
\caption{Add caption} \label{tab:addlabel}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Mechanism} & \textbf{Features} & \textbf{Protocol} & \textbf{Attacks} & \textbf{Limitations}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \ref{tab:addlabel}, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Mechanism} & \textbf{Features} & \textbf{Protocol} & \textbf{Attacks} & \textbf{Limitations}\\
\midrule
\endhead

% footer information
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{Continued on following page}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

% body of longtable
R. Molva et al. & Across domains & Mutual \& One way authentication & Stateless Authentication & Eavesdroppers    & GSM \\
\addlinespace
Hung-Yu et al.  & Subscriber identity& Mutual authentication Non repudiation & Public key & Subscriber ID Compromised session key & GSM \\
\addlinespace
Muxiang Zhang & Fresh key & Mutual authentication \& eliminate synchronisation & AP-AKA symetric key & Redirection attack & 3GPP \\
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively  (with assumption, that other rows have the similar amount of text in cells), you can use smaller font and table set in normal portrait orientation. In this the package `ltablex` can be handy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}%new
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex}% new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{showframe}% only for show page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small% new: smaller font for beter fit table to text width
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l % table width is equal text height
                                  >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L% new column type
                                  >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                                  >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                                  >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                                  l}
\caption{Add caption}\\
    \toprule % added rules
\textbf{Author}  & \textbf{Mechanism} & \textbf{Features} & \textbf{Protocol}   & \textbf{Attacks} & \textbf{Limitations} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
   \toprule % added rules
\textbf{Author}  & \textbf{Mechanism} & \textbf{Features} & \textbf{Protocol}   & \textbf{Attacks} & \textbf{Limitations} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\endfoot
R. Molva et al., & Across domains     & Mutual \& one way authentication
                                                           & Stateless Authentication
                                                                                & Eavesdroppers    & GSM \\
R. Molva et al., & Across domains     & Mutual \& one way authentication
                                                           & Stateless Authentication
                                                                                & Eavesdroppers    & GSM \\
    \addlinespace
Hung-Yu et al.,  & Subscriber identity& Mutual authentication Non repudiation
                                                           & Public key         & Subscriber ID Compromised session key
                                                                                                   & GSM \\
    \addlinespace
Muxiang Zhang    & Fresh key          & Mutual authentication \& eliminate synchronisation & AP-AKA symetric key & Redirection attack & 3GPP \\
    \end{tabularx}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

To obtain final look-out of table at least two compilations are necessary.